# Erro de compilação - java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: input cannot be resolved

Tags: java, compilação

Estou tentando compilar o programa mais abaixo, porém, sempre apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
        input cannot be resolved
        input cannot be resolved
        input cannot be resolved
```

A mesma mensagem tem aparecido tanto nesse caso, quanto em outros. Não posso modificar as entradas, pois fazem parte de um repositório. Como solucionar o problema?
Agradeço a ajuda!

```
    package br.atividade05;
    
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class Question02 {
    
        public static void main(final String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
            int a = input.nextInt();
            int b = input.nextInt(); 
            int c = input.nextIn();
            int maiorab = (a + b + Math.abs(a - b))/2;
            int maiorabc = (maiorab + c + Math.abs(maiorab - c))/2;  
            System.out.printf (maiorabc + " eh o maior");
    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É um erro de compilação. `Input cannot be resolved` significa que não encontrou a variável `input` dentre as variáveis definidas no seu programa. De fato, não existe uma variável declarada como `input` no seu código. O que você quer, de acordo com [essa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43990581/2241463), é fazer `sc.nextInt()` no lugar de `input.nextInt()`. Então basta trocar `input` por `sc` nessas linhas.

Alternativamente, você pode renomear `sc` para `input` na declaração de `Scanner sc`.

Note que `nextIn()` na linha `int c = input.nextIn()` também é um erro de sintaxe, deveria ser `nextInt()` no lugar de `nextIn()`.

Comment: Obrigada! Resolvido.